# Are extra bytes initialized to 0 in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, initialization

Suppose I have a struct that contains an int and a char:

```
struct thing_t {
    int value = 0;
    char other_value = 0;
};
```

Because of the way things are aligned in the memory, `sizeof(thing_t)` should be 8, since the size of the largest member is 4 bytes. If I create a default-initialized instance of `thing_t`, will the extra 3 bytes be initialized to 0?

I recognize that this normally wouldn't come up, but I was writing a hash function and the default behavior of the hash function is to hash a generic type as though it were an array of bytes. If the extra bytes were occasionally not initialized to 0, I realized that my approach could cause problems.

Comment: Padding bytes have undefined contents. IIRC direct manipulation is ok though (compiler generated functions don't guarantee carrying them over on copy or anything else).

Comment: I don't have a reference to the standard to back this up, but you can't rely on them being anything in particular.

Comment: Depending on compiler and your actual case usage, you can probably use a type attribute to define a specific alignment, ie `__attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))`

Comment: In general, in C++, you don't pay for what you don't need/use. That includes stuff not being initialized for you unless you explicitly ask for it to be initialized - since doing so would incur a cost.

Comment: In section `[decl.init]`, it says that they're initialized to zero when initializer is used. I guess it requires parsing of the standard for more clues to be certain. The one I'm referring to is n3797, page 199.

Comment: I think this: _"More commonly, some bits of the object representation may not participate in the value representation at all; such bits may be padding introduced to satisfy alignment requirements, bit field sizes, etc."_ says padding is not part of the value of the object, so no need to consider padding any further because it does not really exist. from:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Comment: Your best bet is to use a custom hash function, or at least a serialization function that creates a string of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

I could not find anything in the C++11 standard about what happens to padding when an object is default initialized.

However, the standard is firm about padding when it comes to *zero-initialization*.

From [8.5 Initializers/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#5)

> 5.2 — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> 5.3 —
> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object's first non-static named data member is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;

I would advise using zero initialization instead of default initialization to force the padding bits to be initialized to zero. That would result in predictable values from your hash function.

Answer (score 4):

> If I create a default-initialized instance of thing_t, will the extra 3 bytes be initialized to 0?

They may or may not be.  There is no requirement for them to be zeroed.

Unfortunately you can't value-initialize the object to get it zero-initialized, which does zero the padding bits, because the default member initalizers stop it from being trivially constructable.

[[dcl.init]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#8)

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> [...]
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, **and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;**

[[class.ctor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor#6)

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> [...]
>
> - no non-static data member of its class has a default member initializer (12.2)